# Can we consider the work stoppage of a sub function as critical issue?

Tags: manual-testing, c#, bug-severity

I'm testing a tool i.e. Draw tool. The tool enables the user to draw on a map using the available graphics and to export drawing from local disk.
The user is able to draw, but export drawing sub function is not working at all. In this case, what do we consider the severity of the defect related to the work stoppage of export tool?

**Note:** Requirement in SRS says that, user should be able to draw on map and export his drawings.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why did you use sub-function instead of function?

Comment: because it is a tool embedded in the main function.

Comment: You need to take this question to the people you work with.  None of us have enough information to tell you how you should categorize your issues.

Answer (score 3):

According to what you have described, it is definitely an issue, but how do you define "critical" in your organisation?

- Is critical of the most severity within your organisation? I personally consider this issue should be a ***show stopper*** as its functionality is not met.

What is the purpose of drawing something but you can not export it?

- You can argue this software is partially working if the user can save it in the default format, but most of users if not all of them will consider export a drawing into a different format or location is a standard feature.

Comment: Critical is workstoppage. So in your openion it is critical since the issue is related to a standalone feature correct?

Comment: It is critical because it is not meeting the specification.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description about the Draw tool, it has two functionality:-
Firstly, it allow user to draw and Secondly allows user to exports its drawing.
Both the functionality makes the tool alive as single one. Otherwise no one will be interested to work on half alive tool.

As per the experience in [software testing services company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company), would suggest this kind of issue to be a critical one and need to be fixed.